# Loading specific scene in Navigation View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

I created a Navigation View Controller. The static table view cell pushes me to a "Personalization" view. So, how can I programmatically load this view from another in this controller hierarchy?

[image]

With this line of code the navigationbar will be hidden…

```
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"personalizationView"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: It depends on where you're coming from in the app. You could do another push segue like Mundi suggested or do an unwind like MarkM suggested. It would be helpful to see how all your controllers are hooked up, and which one you want to call this one from.

Comment: I want to call it from my 'MainViewController' which is not connected by a segue. Normally I do with the code I pasted in

Comment: Is MainViewController not embedded in the navigation controller that your static table view's controller is embedded in? It would be helpful to know where MainViewController fits into the scheme.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem I think :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't embed it in a navigation controller, and then do a push (or hook up a segue) to PersonalizationViewController?

Comment: I found a workaround :) see my answer to to @Mundi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way is to draw another segue from the other view controller.

You can then "push" in code:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowPersonalization" sender:self];
```

Comment: Thank you, I found a workaround. I'm getting some data from my database, which allows to conditionally perform the seque from my 'SettingsViewController'. Simplier as I thought…

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize exit (unwind) segues to accomplish this. Use (UIStoryboardSegue) as an IBAction param on the destination view you wish to exit to and drag from the exit on your viewController to that action to pop directly to that view. IMO this is one of the best kept storyboard secrets and I use them all the time now. ;-)

```
// Exit segue from destinationController
- (IBAction)hitSomethingOnDestination:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue
{
   //
}
```

[Here](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2013/2/5/unwind-segues) is another example of how to use them in a navigation stack